# Symfony 2 and AngularJs Prerender.io not working

Tags: angularjs, symfony, symfony-2.8, prerender

I am working on a single page application using AngularJs and Symfony 2

I wanted to use [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io) to render my pages for SEO.
I downloaded this [Symfony 2 bundle](https://github.com/rjanot/YuccaPrerenderBundle) recommended by prerender.io [official docs](https://prerender.io/documentation).

Unfortunately, prerender.io functionality doesn't seems to be working,

I can't find where to add the cached pages token on this bundle,
And my templates get rendered with its variables without rendering when I test it via [screaming frog tool](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you send us an email with your current configuration? We'd love to look into it for you! support@prerender.io

Comment: I just sent an email with the issue please check it, thanks for your reply